# MikTeX hangs on loading TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, compiling

Normally I use TeXlive in Linux, but recently I've started using MikTeX under Windows 10.  I have just now upgraded MikTeX to its most recent configuration and packages, and I'm using TeXstudio as my editor.

When I include `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble the file simply fails to compile (with PdfLaTeX).  If I remove that one line the compilation proceeds as it should.

In order to try and solve this I opened up the MikTeX Console, and chose "Restart as administrator".  This produced an error:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Data: path="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb"
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MemoryMappedFile\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
Line: 83
```

I'm completely at sea here, and I have no idea on what's causing this error, or how to fix it.  Or why I can't seem to be able to use TikZ.  Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: I have no problem. Run on a command line a minimal example that loads tikz to get a better error message.

Comment: I ran the same file later on in TeXlive on my Linux system and it compiled perfectly.  So it seems the problem is with my MikTeX installation.   But what, I wonder?

Comment: It doesn't help to wonder. You need to find some clues.

Comment: That's why I tried to run the MikTeX Console, only to get the error above.

Comment: The console is not the command line.

Comment: What does it do when you use MikTeX package manager

Comment: I ran the package manager twice to upgrade to the newest versions of all packages - but this problem happened both before and after the upgrade.